# P/Invoke RemoveMenu SetLastError not working

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke

my codes:

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool RemoveMenu(IntPtr hMenu, uint uPosition, uint uFlags);

static void RemoveMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int item, bool byPosition)
{
    if (!RemoveMenu(hMenu, (uint)item, (uint)(byPosition ? 0x400 : 0)))
    {
        throw new Win32Exception();
    }
}

RemoveMenu(xxx, -1, false); //got exception and it's message is: The operation completed successfully.
```

This means that API didn't Set the LastError when it failed. why and how?

[RemoveMenu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-removemenu#return-value) API doc.

Comment: It successfully could not remove menu item #4294967295.  It does not exist.  You could use Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() to prevent throwing the exception.  But realistically you'd fix the code to specify a correct menu item.

Comment: Thank you comment first. I'm writting a component, not caller, so i hope it throw out a correct error when failed. now if `hMenu` is a invalid handle, it's worked, but if item is a not exists item, error message is incorrect.

Comment: "*but if item is a not exists item, error message is incorrect.*" Try to first use [`GetMenuItemInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmenuiteminfoa) to check if the item exists.(error code = `ERROR_MENU_ITEM_NOT_FOUND` if it doesn't exist)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the behavior is not wrong. The documentation merely says to call `GetLastError()` on failure, but it doesn't say that `GetLastError()` can't return 0 as the reason. And indeed, at least according to [CMenu::RemoveMenu  is failing](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20531930/), 0 is actually what is reported (though something like `ERROR_MENU_ITEM_NOT_FOUND` would have made more sense).

This is very easy to work around, using `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` before throwing the `Win32Exception`:

```pascal
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool RemoveMenu(IntPtr hMenu, uint uPosition, uint uFlags);

static void RemoveMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int item, bool byPosition)
{
    if (!RemoveMenu(hMenu, (uint)item, (uint)(byPosition ? 0x400 : 0)))
    {
        int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (err != 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(err);
    }
}

RemoveMenu(xxx, -1, false);
```

Comment: *"return 0 as the reason"* Actually, as I tested, it does not set last error, I call `setlasterror` before `RemoveMenu`. And then call `getlasterror`: get the same value set in `setlasterror`. I will confirm this behavior internally.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT if that is true, then the documentation is wrong.

Comment: The problem is that when the item does not exist, the API does not SetLastError, so GetLastWin32Error is the result of other APIs, this is unreliable. But now I think I understand this design. In reality, deleting an item that no longer exists should not report an error. it's a expected result, so just handle `code == ERROR_INVALID_MENU_HANDLE` enough.

Comment: @ahdung if that were true, then you would expect it to return `true` instead of `false`, but it is not. And how do you expect to get `ERROR_INVALID_MENU_HANDLE` if `SetLastError()` is not being called?

Comment: @rem I agree this API should return true when item not exists, if return false, it must set last error. as for `ERROR_INVALID_MENU_HANDLE`, in my test, it's work fine.